# Find partial derivatives of $f(x, y)=\sqrt[3]{xy}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x, y)=\sqrt[3]{xy}$. Find $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$. Is $f$ differential at (0,0)?
How can I do?

Comment: Where are you stuck?
Also, what do you mean by "is $f$ differentiable?"?. Are you talking about total differentiability or something else?

Comment: I wonder how to prove or disprove that function is differential. I am talking about total derivative as follow:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}=
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x \cdot 0}-\sqrt[3]{0}}{x}=\ldots
$$
and similarly for $\partial f/\partial y$. Now you have a *candidate* to be $Df(0,0)$. You should check if
$$
\lim_{|(h,k)| \to 0} \frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-Df(0,0)(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0.
$$

Comment: Yes, I wrote it at a generic point $(x,y)$. Now I've edited my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Write the expression as $x^{1/3}y^{1/3}$.

For $f_x$, treat $y$ as a constant; for $f_y$, treat $x$ as a constant.

Try to plug in $x=0$ and $y=0$ *after* you have taken the partial derivatives.

Is there a problem when you try to do this last step? What does it say about differentiability at that point?